# React-selectize unable to load css

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, stylesheet, react-select

I'm using node and npm install react-selectize

When I finishing implementing  component in React JS, it doesn't have any css on it when displayed.

And I looked at node package, it has several *.styl node_module.

How should I be able to load those *.styl ?
I use scss for our styling.

Answer (score 0):

Did you link the CSS file to the HTML?

EX. `<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "FILENAME.EXTENSION">`

(this code is for HTML)

Comment: I dont think it links to *.styl, instead I copy code from it, and manually write out to *.css.

Comment: @Daniel.zZ you can only link .js and .css files i think